# ISICE07: Component ... is installed to the Global Assembly Cache. This requires a waiver

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, installshield

Installing an assembly to the GAC seems insanely difficult to do properly. There are many pages on SO describing how to do so. I picked one that said to add the file as a component to an MSI installer in InstallShield and set the destination to GlobalAssemblyCache. When I do this, I get an error nobody else seems to be encountering yet, so maybe it's new with InstallShield 2015:

> ISDEV : error ISICE07: Component TestLib.Primary_output is installed
>   to the Global Assembly Cache. This requires a waiver for Windows 7
>   Logo Certification.   Component   Directory_  TestLib.Primary_output

There has got to be a proper way to install an assembly into the GAC. It's not with GacUtil. That's for development purposes only. It's not with a direct copy to windows\assembly because that can move depending on the version of .NET and probably other reasons too. It's apparently not by setting the install target to GlobalAssemblyCache in InstallShield.

**Edit:**
I managed to disable the validation in InstallShield, which affected the Install project created in Visual Studio. Now I can install and see the assembly in the GAC. But I don't feel like this is a complete answer to this validation error. If this is not the right way to install an assembly into the GAC, what *is*?

Comment: You appear to have the MPR Test Tool installed on your machine.  Is this intentional?  Why didn't you mention this in your question?  Next logical step is to uninstall it.

Comment: @HansPassant I added an edit to clarify the issue around the validation being applied. My question still remains, what is the right way to avoid this validation error other than just disabling the validation?

Comment: Sigh, InstallShield is marketed to make it *easier* to create installers and it forever does the exact opposite.  You are supposed to buy the support plan, that's how they afford their Ferraris.  Are you *actually* trying to obtain the Windows Logo for your app?  Then don't create a DLL Hell problem, nobody likes to deal with that.  Once you install a DLL into the GAC then you bought the farm, you can't reasonably remove it again.

Comment: In the applications I designed, I avoid the GAC like the plague (is that what you're suggesting?) In this case I'm dealing with an application designed by others for which I need to design the install. If you're suggesting avoiding the GAC then I'll push back to see if it's necessary, but chances are we'll still have some components going in the GAC. I thought putting components in and out of the GAC was a simple matter of implementing the right Install class like it is for an MMC snap-in. But I can't find any documentation for a simple non-MMC assembly that needs to go in the GAC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern installation procedures are much more capable of letting things run outside of the GAC than I realized. I also forgot about registration-free COM activation which might also be involved. I think my answer for now is to avoid the GAC. The components I was trying to install into the GAC work just fine outside the GAC. They are relied upon by an MMC snap-in, but InstallShield/MSI seems to magically figure out how to install all the components so they work without using the GAC.